# Aggregated Correlation (R::dplyr)

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate a correlation matrix at various subsettings of a data frame.  I found this snippet of code for calculating correlation between 2 variables in the data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(V1=cor(hp,wt))
```

But I would like to calculate a correlation matrix between several variables in the data frame.  I would like this to be returned (preferably) as a list of correlation matrixes. Something like:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% cor(data.frame(hp,wt,qsec)
```

Can I do that with dplyr?

Comment: It's calculating correlation between `hp` and `wt` for each separate `cyl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion good old `by` or `dlply` is better here, but if you really want to use `dplyr`, I think you can use `do`:

```
o <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(cor=cor(cbind(.$hp, .$wt, .$qsec)))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>

#   cyl        cor
# 1   4 <dbl[3,3]>
# 2   6 <dbl[3,3]>
# 3   8 <dbl[3,3]>
```

where the `.` refers to the filtered dataframe. Then you could do `o$cor[1]` etc. I'm unsure how to just get a list output from dplyr rather than a dataframe output.

---

Using plyr:

```
library(plyr)
dlply(mtcars, .(cyl), function (x) cor(x[, c('hp', 'wt', 'qsec')]))
```

Using base R and `by`:

```
o <- by(mtcars[, c('hp', 'wt', 'qsec')], mtcars$cyl, cor, simplify=F)
```

`o` is of class `by`, but `?by` says this is basically a list.

```
length(o) # 3
names(o) # "4" "6" "8" (i.e. the cyl values)
o[[1]] # =cor(hp, wt, qsec) where cyl==4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer was very comprehensive @mathematical.coffee. I am not committed to dplyr, I'm just trying to learn it at the moment. Maybe one day I will evolve to a stage of enlightenment where all data manipulations reduce to base R commands. :)

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(o, \`[\`, lower.tri(o[[1]])))` or something similar after the `by` call would allow for the bivariate correlations to be reported one by one for each group.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'm updating here in case it's helpful to folks.

You can use the functions in the `purrr` package to transform the tibble containing correlation matrices to a list of objects that can be further manipulated.

Specifically, to expand on the answer provided by @mathematical.coffee:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>% 
  dplyr::do(cor = cor(cbind(.$hp, .$wt, .$qsec))) %>%
  purrr::transpose() %>%     # <- converts tibble to a row-wise list
  purrr::set_names(nm = purrr::map(., 'cyl')) %>%  # <- use `cyl` as item name
  purrr::map('cor')      # <- extract `cor` from each list item
```

The result is a list of correlation matrices:

```r
$`4`
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000 0.1598761 -0.1783611
[2,]  0.1598761 1.0000000  0.6380214
[3,] -0.1783611 0.6380214  1.0000000

$`6`
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.3062284 -0.6280148
[2,] -0.3062284  1.0000000  0.8659614
[3,] -0.6280148  0.8659614  1.0000000

$`8`
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.00000000 0.01761795 -0.7554985
[2,]  0.01761795 1.00000000  0.5365487
[3,] -0.75549854 0.53654866  1.0000000
```

The key part of this is the [purrr::transpose()](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/transpose.html) function, which casts the `tibble` to a list of columns before transposing it to a list of rows.